# I have a super old windows computer and a mac how to put linux on the windows pc?

Tags: system-installation

I want to revive my old computer (late 2012) with linux and I have a mac. I want to put linux on a hard drive using my mac and then plug the hard drive onto the windows computer and install linux on it.
How do i do this?

Comment: I would recommend that you create an Ubuntu USB stick, boot from that and install Ubuntu on your old computer. I don't see any reason to use the Mac at all (however you could create the USB stick on the Mac if you wanted to). Instructions are on the official [Ubuntu site](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Comment: how do i create the stick?

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: I actually provided a link in my original post - did you bother to click it?

Comment: I wondered if the OP asked because they want to do it on macos; thus my *bunch* of links that cover doing it on ubuntu, windows or macos, plus validation of iso & tutorial on installing...   You did try @ArturMeinild

Comment: Yeah, every USB stick tutorial on Ubuntu.com cross-link between the Ubuntu, Windows and MacOS versions. I figured this was self explanatory when you read their guides.

Comment: @guiverc  after reading OP's question again, I am thinking maybe he wants to do installing with his mac and then place hard drive into PC to boot up.  Will your links help or is there extra instructions he needs?

Comment: @crip659 the issue is, why would you gain anything using this method rather than to create an USB stick, which has a very detailed guide on Ubuntu.com? I only foresee additional problems using the method suggested in the OP, which is why I suggested the "preferred" method of installation instead.

Comment: @Artur Meinild Hard drive and/or USB ports cooked on PC.  Agree there are easier ways to install on most systems.  OP might just want to see if it works.

Comment: I realize that @crip659 , however I agree with Artur's initial recommendation against that approach.. The hardware may not be alike between the two boxes...

Answer (score 0):

as you have mentioned it's an old machine, here are the some of the alternatives(linux OS) for old machines which you can install :

/
[1. Linux Lite](https://www.linuxliteos.com/) 
/
[2. Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) 
/
[3. Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) 
/
[4. Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.com/) 
/
[5. Best Lightweight Linux Distributions For Older Computers](https://itsfoss.com/lightweight-linux-beginners/) 
/

/
How to install Linux on old Windows Machine :

/

1. https://www.instructables.com/id/Bring-new-life-to-an-old-laptop-with-Ubuntu/ 
   /
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3aCdxjOySE

   /
   Hope it helps. Stay Safe.

Comment: I'm not sure a series of links are a good answer, and if you're going to provide links, please use correct ones. You haven't included a Lubuntu link, but have provided a *fan* site.  If unsure of correct links, check on ubuntu.com (ie. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours will send you to official web sites for each Ubuntu *flavor*)